# Which certificate should be use in SSLContext when using self-signed certificate? Self-sign certificate or the ca certificate

Tags: android, ssl

I am very confused about the certificate used in ssl on android. Regularly, one should use ca.crt(ca certificate) to verify the server.crt(certificate) in client. However, it seems that either ca.crt and server.crt can work when using ssl on android. That is very strange. Can someone explain what happen?

Thanks in advance.

As the code show below, I can use ca.crt or server.crt to build client.bks. Both of them can successfully connect to the server. BTW, after I rebuild the server.crt in server side with other inforamtion, I can only use ca.crt to connect the server.

```java
KeyStore trustKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream keyStream = xxxApplication.getInstance().getAssets().open("client.bks");

trustKeyStore.load(keyStream, "".toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustKeyStore);
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

---

In another way, I want to know how the SSL in android verify the server certificate with the TrustManagers. Let's call the the certificate I use to build trustManager 'client.crt'. It seem that the below code allow the server certificates(both the certificate client.crt and the certificate which can be verified by client.crt).

Comment: That's depends on what you want to do. Do you want to trust a specific server certificate only or do you want to trust all certificates issued by a specific CA?

Comment: If they both work, it isn't a self-signed certificate. You should use the CA certificate. You can't 'rebuild' a certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the reply. Actually, I want to trust all certificates issued by a specific CA. Can you tell me how to trust a specific certificate and how to trust   all certificates issued by a specific CA in Android? I am confused about why the code show above can work with both server.crt and ca.crt.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for the reply. The code show above actually work for both certificates. I know I should use a CA certificate to trust  all certificates issued by that CA. I am confused about why I use server.crt in client side can work(The server side return the self-signed server.crt in handshake). BTW, I 'rebuid' a certificate in server sider means that I use server.key and ca.key to generate a new certificate.

Comment: It works *because it isn't a self-signed certificate.* I've already stated that.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a TLS handshake, each party can have a certificate (with associated private key) that it exposes to the other party to identify itself.

It is frequent that only the server certificate matters, like in HTTPS, but in general a client can also present a certificate, if requested by the server.

In broad terms the exchange goes like this:

- client: hello
- server: I have certificate X
- (if server wants client to present a certificate) server: client, please send me your certificate, I recognize CAs A, B, C, D
- (if server asked for a certificate) client: here is my certificate Y

What does that mean?

When the server asks the client for its certificate it lists which CAs it knows about, that is it guides the client into choosing the appropriate certificate (a client can have more than one in its truststore so it needs to pick one - it can send only one - either by some automated way or at the end by asking some human to pick one)

This is only a guidance, a client can send whatever certificate it wants, signed by any CA it likes... but risks the certificate to be rejected by the server then.

So when you configure the client part, to build an "SSL context" you need to specify your certificate, your private key associated to the certificate, optionally a list of certificates called "chain" or "intermediate", as all of this without the private key will need to be sent to the server, and separately configure your side to recognize some CAs as fully trusted, so that you will use them to authenticate the server certificate.

The chain/intermediate ones are because end-user/system certificates are rarely (never?) signed directly by a CA certificate (except if self-signed of course in which case the end certificate is also the CA certificate), so the client needs in fact to send both its end certificate and the whole chain of certificates needed to link its end certificate to one of the CA certificate (the "root" CA certificate does not need to be sent). With all that information, the server will be able to authenticate the client, using its certificate, and all intermediate ones, and the CA certificates the server has in its own local trust store.

If you configure your side with a "real" CA (public or private), it means you will accept any server (for that part of the checks, there are other checks, like on dates, signature value of course, names included in certificate, etc.) that is able to present a certificate issued by this CA (through some intermediate ones again). If instead you use there directly the server self signed certificate it means you will allow in fact only this certificate, and not anyone else (so no other server, and not even that specific server once you change its self signed certificate).

Note that in first step (`clientHello`), the client can also list which CAs it knows about (see §4.2.4 of RFC8446), but I believe this to be rare.

Comment: The client cannot send a certificate that doesn't comply with the parameters in the CertificateRequest message.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, but it can, as I witnessed myself. In one specific setup, the server wanted to accept many CAs for the client certificate, but they do not all fit in the CertificateRequest due to its size limit. So it sends "some" of them, as many as it can, but still accepts back certificate from the client with other CAs, as the list of CAs in the request is more for the client to be able to pick appropriate certificate to use as some languages (Java) depend on that.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the reply. I just want the client verify the server(so I do not need provider key and client certificates in client side). You mentioned that 'separately configure your side to recognize some CAs as fully trusted, so that you will use them to authenticate the server certificate'. However, in android I can use either 'server.crt'(which I think using it to verify itself is impossible)  or 'ca.crt' to authenticate the server certificate(server.crt) with same code.

Comment: Maybe certain implementations do, but it is a violation of the RFC, and therefore not to be relied on.

Comment: @user207421 I wouldn't be so definitive for the simple reason that the message is size limited. So what should clients and servers do if their CA list is just too big to fit in it?

Comment: @user207421 It is not a violation of the RFC. See RFC8446 §4.2.4 "The "certificate_authorities" extension is used to indicate the
   certificate authorities (CAs) which an endpoint supports and which
   SHOULD be used by the receiving endpoint to guide certificate
   selection." Note specifically the "SHOULD" which is not a "MUST", so clients are totally allowed to pick a certificate from another CA, and also the last part "to guide certificate selection", which is not "to force only certificates from the given CAs".

Answer (score 0):

As the results I observe, I believe the default trustManagerFactory in android will accept two types of certificates. One contains the certificates we load in trustManagerFactory. The other contains the certificates which can be correctly verified by the certificates we load.

So one can load server certificate to trust a specific certificate, or he can load ca certificate to trust a set of certificates which can be verified by that ca certificate.